# Recursive method to replace all occurrences of a value in a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array

I have created a recursive method that replaces all occurrences of an element in a two dimensional double array. The issue is that I cannot seem to get this working without encountering a stack overflow error. Could someone please look at my code below and show me how to fix this? I have tried setting this up several times over the past few days. Thank you. Note that my arrays are 2 x 3, so the first if means that if you are at column 1 row 2, you are at the end of the array, and in that case you are done searching.

```java
private static int replaceAll(double number, double replacementTerm) {
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    double searchFor = number;
    double replace = replacementTerm;

    if (i == 1 && j == 2) {
        System.out.println("Search complete!");
    }

    if (twoDimArray2[i][j] == searchFor) {
        System.out.println("Replaced An Element!");
        twoDimArray2[i][j] = replace;
        System.out.println(twoDimArray2[i][j]);
        j++;
        return replaceAll(searchFor, replace);
    }

    if (j == twoDimArray2.length) {
        i++;
        return replaceAll(searchFor, replace);
    } else {
        j++;
        return replaceAll(searchFor, replace);
    }
}
```

Comment: `i++` and `j++` only modify local variables - Java doesn't have static local variables. Passing `i` and `j` as parameters would fix that. However, I'd suggest iteration instead of recursion, since you know the array is 2D anyways

Comment: How can `if(i == 1 && j == 2) {` be true, you have only just declared these variables within this method? Try making them parameters or fields

Comment: @user: I would love to use iteration - but this is a school project that has to do with a chapter on recursion - so I'm guessing this is the way it has to be. I will totally pass i and j as parameters.

Comment: and thank you also to @scaryWombat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` and `j` should be method parameters instead of local variables so changes to their values can be tracked. Try to move right and down recursively if it does not exceed the bounds of the array. Note that this is much less efficient that iteration with two layers of `for` loops, as it will check multiple positions in the array more than once; to mitigate this, one can use a visited array to store all positions previous visited so they will not be checked again. See the below code in action [here](https://ideone.com/1EtiW3).

```
private static void replaceAll(double number, double replacementTerm, int i, int j) {
    double searchFor = number;
    double replace = replacementTerm;
    if (twoDimArray2[i][j] == searchFor) {
        System.out.println("Replaced An Element!");
        twoDimArray2[i][j] = replace;
        System.out.println(twoDimArray2[i][j]);
    }
    if (i == twoDimArray2.length - 1 && j == twoDimArray2[0].length - 1) {
        System.out.println("Reached the end!");
        return;
    }
    if (i + 1 < twoDimArray2.length) {
        replaceAll(number, replacementTerm, i + 1, j);
    }
    if (j + 1 < twoDimArray2[0].length) {
        replaceAll(number, replacementTerm, i, j + 1);
    }
}
```

Comment: I cannot thank you enough for your answer. I was stumped on this for days. I am curious - why is right and down the correct way to do this'

Comment: @JulieS No problem. You move right and down because you start from (0,0) and want to cover the rest of the matrix. Thus, you will want to continuously move right and move down until you reach the last cell.

Comment: That makes sense. I don't know why in my head when I saw the term right and down, I actually envisioned traversing backwards through the array. I actually saw an example online that did that - but didn't make any sense to me. Thank you again and if you celebrate, Happy 4th of July.